# What is the difference between superposition and paramodulation?

Tags: first-order-logic, automated-theorem-proving

I am currently writing a paper about automated theorem proving in first-order logic. Equality is not uncommon for mathematical problems and almost every theorem prover like VAMPIRE or SPASS has a calculus for equality. But the most paper are always writing about the term "superposition" calculus. A simple google search did not help to find any information about this term, only the wikipedia website which means "it can be used for first-order logic with equality".

Another paper referneced to the [Paramodulation-based theorem proving](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.34.9958&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which describes the concept of paramodulation for theorem proving. It seems that the superposition is some modified version of paramodulation, but I don't understand why and in which way.

So, is there any explanation of this calculus or can someone give me some hints what is different from paramodulation?

Answer (score 5):

This is late for you, but probably might be of help to others. I myself had asked this question and I wrote the summary of my findings to the acl2-help mailing list on 8 and 9 September 2013: https://utlists.utexas.edu/sympa/arc/acl2-help/2013-09/msg00005.html
https://utlists.utexas.edu/sympa/arc/acl2-help/2013-09/msg00006.html

Disclaimer: What follows is my understanding of the subject and I am not an expert.

I assume you are familiar with what is called
term-rewriting. Informally its a very simple notion where one uses a
rule to reduce or rewrite another expression.

A rewrite rule is usually a universally quantified formula of the form
$C \Rightarrow l=r$, where $C$ is a formula and $l$ and $r$ are terms. One says that a
rule $R$ applies to another formula $\Phi$, if there is some subterm $s$ of
$\Phi$ and some substitution $\sigma$ such that $l\sigma = s$ (this process
is called matching) and $C\sigma$ is true. If $R$ applies to $\Phi$, then
one can rewrite $\Phi$ to $\Phi\sigma$. Demodulation is another name for
unconditional term-rewriting, i.e., $C$ is simply true and so $R$ is just
$l=r$.

Rewriting involves matching,i.e., one-way unification. 
Paramodulation involves full unification.  Moreover, the equality
($l=r$) that is used to perform paramodulation, is not directed, either
lhs or rhs can be unified with a subterm in the other literal
paramodulated upon.

Superposition is a restriction of Paramodulation. In particular, the
rules of inference named 'Superposition (left/right)' are restrictions
of "ordered" paramodulation, i.e., the paramodulation rule is applied
only when equation $l=r$ (to be instantiated/unified) satisfies certain
properties: $l >> r$ for a given reduction order $>>$, $l=r$ is maximal (wrt
$>>$) in the clause etc etc.

Here are some fundamental papers that are interesting from a historical point of view.

[1] The concept of demodulation in theorem proving - L Wos, GA
Robinson, DF Carson, L Shalla - Journal of the ACM (JACM), 1967

[2] Handbook of Logic and Automated Reasoning - J Harrison.

[3] Paramodulation and theorem-proving in first-order theories with
equality- G Robinson, L Wos - Machine intelligence, 1969

[4] Rewrite-based equational theorem proving with selection and
simplification - L Bachmair, H Ganzinger - Journal of Logic and
Computation, 1994

[5] Simple word problems in universal algebras - DE Knuth, PB Bendix -
Computational problems in abstract algebra 1970

[6] A superposition oriented theorem prover - L Fribourg - Theoretical
Computer Science, 1985 - Elsevier

[7] Completion without failure - L Bachmair, N Dershowitz, DA Plaisted -1989

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good answers to older questions are always appreciated. One of the goals of the site is to be useful to anybody who might be wondering about a question, not just the person who originally asked it, so your first sentence is exactly right. :-)

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you. The two links are dead. Any chance you could revive them?